# Automatically decrease cell 'b1' with the same value that I increased with cell 'a1'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Cell 1 and Cell 2.  I want to increase Cell 1 by 5 and decrease Cell 2 the same number as what I have increased in Cell 1.  Is there a way to automatically do this and not changing the value of Cell 2 manually?  I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2007.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just do the maths and reference a cell?

So, in Cell 3 have the number 5.

In cell 1 do "current value + Cell3"
In cell 2 do "current value - Cell3"

Comment: Example:  Originally, I put 6 in Cell 1 and 8 in Cell 2.  Then I decrease Cell 1 and make it 4, I want Cell 2 to automatically become 10.  Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Are you not able to put the figure into cell 3 with a - or + ? So, Cell 1 is 6 and Cell 2 is 8 and 3 is empty. Entering -3 in Cell 3 will obviously subtract 3 from both cells, and like ways for addition.

Answer (score 1):

Add this VBA code then enter a value in column C to change A and B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If (Target.Cells.Count <> 1) Then Exit Sub  ' one cell only
  If (Target = "") Then Exit Sub  ' if we pressed delete, do nothing more

  If (Target.Column = 3)  Then   ' we entered value in column C
    With Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -2)  ' add it to A
      .Value = .Value + Target
    End With
    With Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -1)  ' subtract it from B
      .Value = .Value - Target
    End With
    Target.ClearContents

    Exit Sub
  End If

End Sub
```